# Styling input radio with css

Tags: css, input

I have this slideshow with `[input type="radio"]`: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/23/
Codes: CSS:

```
#slideselector {
    position: absolue;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
.slidebutton {
    height: 21px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

I'm trying to style the input radio with css so it looks like that: [image] any suggestions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/25/)**

**CSS**

```
#slideselector {
    position: absolue;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
.slidebutton {
    height: 21px;
    margin: 2px;
}
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.imgLike {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
/* Radio */

input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 20%, hsla(0,0%,100%,.7), transparent 80%),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 20%, hsla(0,0%,100%,.7), transparent 80%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),
                0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.6),
                0 2px 3px hsla(0,0%,0%,.6),
                0 4px 3px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                0 6px 6px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                0 10px 6px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:after {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.8);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 7px;
    left: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    width: 7px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
    background-color: #f66;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                inset 0 2px 2px hsla(0,0%,100%,.4),
                0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),
                0 0 2px 2px hsla(0,70%,70%,.4);
}
```

Comment: Not working on my codes which you can see here: jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/23

Comment: @system-x32z i have update my answer please check now

Comment: Seems like your styling only works on Chrome (tested browsers: IE10, Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: It is not a good idea to use appearance on production sites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple example of how you can do this.

Just replace the image file and you are done.

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" />
<label for="r1"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
<p>
<input type="radio" id="r2" name="rr" />
<label for="r2"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(check_radio_sheet.png) -57px top no-repeat;
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFFbz/)

Comment: In your code you need to add `<label for="r2"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>` after creating `radio` and using my css code you can do this.

Comment: @DipeshParmar using `input[type="radio"] { display:none; }` will take out keyboard access from the radio buttons. It will fail the accessibility test. Do you know a work around to this.?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some background image to your radio buttons and flip it with another image on change

```
.radio {
    background: url(customButton.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Not working on my codes which you can see here: jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/23

Answer (score 0):

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/24/)**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-2-1" name="radio-2-set" class="regular-radio" /><label for="radio-2-1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio-2-2" name="radio-2-set" class="regular-radio" /><label for="radio-2-2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio-2-3" name="radio-2-set" class="regular-radio" /><label for="radio-2-3"></label>

.regular-radio {
    display: none;
}

.regular-radio + label {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border: 4px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

.regular-radio:checked + label {
    background: grey;
    border: 4px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: Not working on my codes which you can see here: jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/23

Answer (score 0):

**[Trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine))** provides the `::-ms-check` pseudo-element for checkbox and radio button controls. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="radio">

::-ms-check {
    color: red;
    background: black;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This displays as follows in IE10 on Windows 8:

[image]